# Delphi7 TIniFile Usage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Am trying to create an ini file to save the an application configuration.
the saving part works perfect with the input from the edit boxes 1,2,3 etc here is the ini sample

```
[1server]
SSHHost=ssh.com
SSHPort=443
Username=user
Password=123
[2server]
SSHHost=ssh.com
SSHPort=443
Username=user
Password=123
[ProxySettings]
Proxy=127.0.0.1
Port=8080
Type=http
```

how do i make the app read the saved ini setting on launching it and is it possible to hide or encrypt user saved password?

Comment: You should look at how other programs tackle things like ssh passwords.

Comment: @KenWhite 
Here is my code line to read the config file when i try to run the app   nothing is applied in the edit boxes 

    `procedure TForm1.actReloadExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadIniFile;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadIniFile;
var
MyIni: Tinifile;
begin
myINI := TINIFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.ssh'));
try
Edit3.Text :=Myini.ReadString('1server', 'SSHHost', '');
finally
myINI.Free;
end;
end;`

Comment: If you feel the need to add more details, [edit] your question to do so there where they can be seen and where code can be properly formatted and easily read. If you're not getting values back with the code you posted, either the ini file isn't where you think it is or you don't have values saved for `SSHHost` for `1server` in your ini file.

Answer (score 3):

Simply read the Ini file in your main form's `FormCreate` event.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ini: TIniFile;
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(YourIniFileName);
  try
    // The final parameter to all of the `ReadXx` functions is a default
    // value to use if the value doesn't exist.
    Edit1.Text := Ini.ReadString('1server', 'SSHHost', 'No host found');
    Edit2.Text := Ini.ReadString('1server', 'SSHPort', 'No port found');
    // Repeat, using ReadString, ReadInteger, ReadBoolean, etc.
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

One word of caution: `TIniFile` has known issues with writing to network locations, so if there's any chance of that you should use `TMemIniFile` instead. `TIniFile` wraps the WinAPI INI support functions (`ReadPrivateProfileString` and others), while `TMemIniFile` is written totally in Delphi code and doesn't suffer from the same problems. They're syntax-compatible and in the same unit, so it's a simple matter of changing `TIniFile` to `TMemIniFile` in your variable declaration and the line that creates the `Ini`:

```
var
  Ini: TMemIniFile;
begin
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(YourIniFileName);
  ...
end;
```

As far as encrypting the password, you can use any encryption algorithm you want, as long as the encrypted value can be converted to a textual representation. (Ini files don't handle binary values.) The choice of algorithm is up to you based on the level of security you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: I dont know where i might be going wrong but its still failing

Comment: As I said in my last comment to your question, it's failing because either a) the INI file isn't where you think it is (or isn't named what you think it is), or b) you don't have values in there for the section and entry you're trying to read. Those are the *only* two reasons the code won't work. So do some troubleshooting: Add a test for `FileExists(YourIniFileName)` before trying to create the `TIniFile` and see what happens, and assign the results of your `ChangeFileExt` code to a variable before trying to use it so you can inspect the contents in the debugger. I can't do either of those.

Comment: Don't encrypt the password, hash it.

Comment: @Shambhala: I'm doing neither. Did you intend to post this as a comment to the original question instead? (The *encryption* was a side question not related directly to the issue, which is why I didn't address it in depth.)

Comment: @KenWhite - It should indeed really have been a comment to the original question, sorry about that.

Comment: @Shambhala: No harm. I just wasn't sure if I'd missed something. :-)